# nginx - valid_referes dont work

Tags: nginx

I have the local server running on 3000 port and it sends some POST request to nginx server. Nginx should check referer, if it is not coming from 127.0.0.1:3000 (with all subdomains) then return 403 Restricted,otherwise if it is valid redirect to 9200/errors/browser endpoint.

Currently, it is always redirecting regardless if the referer is valid or not. I know that in nginx if is evil , so if-else approach doesnt work here.

```
server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:9999;
  server_name localhost;      

  location / {

      valid_referers none blocked server_names ~someaddress;

      if ($invalid_referer) {
          return 403;
      }

      # redirect to this endpoint if referer is valid    
      return 307 http://localhost:9200/errors/browser;    

  }
}
```

Comment: `Referer` is what you see in browser's address bar. Do you really see `127.0.0.1:3000` there?

Comment: And anyway, I don't see `127.0.0.1:3000` in your list of valid referers

Answer (score -1):

I should add

```
if ($invalid_referer != "1") {
   return 403;
}
```

as it is the empty string according to the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html)

> $invalid_referer
>   Empty string, if the “Referer” request header field value is considered valid, otherwise “1”.

Comment: Empty `$invalid_referer` means referrer is valid. Why do you want return 403 to valid referer?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, right, I should edit it, the right option is `$invalid_referer != "1"` Thanks

Comment: well, then please propose yours, i'm here looking for the answer, suggestions instead of giving me hint that this is wrong or not!